# How to use the expand function in Snakemake to make permutations or combinations of a list

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

probably a very basic question in Snakemake but I couldn't find the answer so far. Say I have a list of samples

```
SAMPLES = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

A typical `expand` command would look like:

```
expand("{sample}.txt", sample=SAMPLES)
```

But I would like to get combinations (or even permutations) of the same samples list.

Doing:

```
expand("{sample}-{sample}.txt", sample=SAMPLES)
```

would give you

```
 A-A.txt, A-B.txt, A-C.txt, B-A.txt, B-B.txt, B-C.txt, C-A.txt, C-B.txt, C-C.txt
```

Instead I want:

```
A-B.txt, A-C.txt, B-C.txt
```

In the Snakemake documentation for the [expand function](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=wildcards#the-expand-function) they say:

"Per default, expand uses the python itertools function `product` that yields all combinations of the provided wildcard values. However by inserting a second positional argument this can be replaced by any combinatoric function, e.g. `zip`"

However, I cannot just replace `product` with the [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function because, as far as I can tell from the [source code of expand](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/snakemake/io.html#expand), you can't give the `r` (length of the output tuples) argument to `expand`. Doing

```
import itertools
expand("{sample}-{sample}.txt", itertools.combinations, sample=SAMPLES)
```

Returns an error of `'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. But it works with `itertools.product`.

I guess I could create two lists outside of the rules with `itertools.combinations` before calling expand, but I was hoping for an elegant way of doing it from the Snakemake community.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it can be done within `expand` but I think it would be easier to generate the list of interest without it. E.g.:

```
SAMPLES = ["A", "B", "C"]

combs = []
for x in itertools.combinations(SAMPLES, 2):
    combs.append('%s-%s.txt' %(x[0], x[1]))

print(combs)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
['A-B.txt', 'A-C.txt', 'B-C.txt']
```

Now use `combs` wherever you would have used `expand(...)`. Consider that `expand` is just a convenience function that returns a list but you don't have to necessarily use it

Comment: Thanks! Indeed one can use it like you suggested, I did something similar myself, but I was hopping for a more "direct" solution :). It seems like something that would be useful within the expand function.

Comment: From what I see on stackoverflow, this `expand` feature of Snakemake seems to be the one that creates most confusion on users. Basic knowledge of python sometimes makes things simpler. Actually, I would call a simple plain Python solution more "direct" than a solution based on the use of expand.