# 'expand' won't do what I want. How do I generate a custom list of inputs to a rule in Snakemake?

Tags: python, snakemake

I want to run a Snakemake workflow where the input is defined by a combination of different variables (e.g. pairs of samples, sample ID and Nanopore barcode,...):

```py
sample_1 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
sample_2 = ["spam", "ham", "eggs"]
```

I've got a rule using these:

```
rule frobnicate:
    input:
        assembly = "{first_sample}_{second_sample}.txt"
    output:
        frobnicated = "{first_sample}_{second_sample}.frob"
```

I now want to create a rule `all` that will do this for *some* combinations of the samples in `sample_1` and `sample_2`, but not all of them.

Using `expand` would give me *all* possible combinations of `sample_1` and `sample_2`.

How can I, for example, just combine the first variable in the first list with the first in the second and so on (`foo_spam.frob`, `bar_ham.frob`, and `baz_eggs.frob`)?

And what if I want some more complex combination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using `expand` with other combinatoric functions

By default, [`expand` uses the itertools function `product`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html). However, it's possible to specify another function for `expand` to use. 
To combine the first variable in the first with the first in the second and so on, one can tell `expand` to use `zip`:

```py
sample_1 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
sample_2 = ["spam", "ham", "eggs"]
```

```
rule all:
    input: expand("{first_sample}_{second_sample}.frob", zip, first_sample=sample_1, second_sample=sample_2)
```

will yield `foo_spam.frob`, `bar_ham.frob`, and `baz_eggs.frob` as inputs to `rule all`.

#### Using regular Python code to generate your list

The input generated by `expand` is ultimately just a list of file names. If you can't get where you want to with `expand` and another combinatoric function, it could be easier to just use regular Python code to generate the list yourself (for an example of this in action, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450853/how-to-use-the-expand-function-in-snakemake-to-make-permutations-or-combinations)).

#### The brute-force solution: just write the list yourself

If your combination of inputs can't be arrived at programmatically *at all*, one last resort would be to write out the combinations you want by hand. For example:

```py
sample_1 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
sample_2 = ["spam", "ham", "eggs"]
all_frobnicated = ["foo_eggs.frob", "bar_spam.frob", "baz_ham.frob"]
```

```
rule all:
    input: all_frobnicated
```

This will, of course, mean your inputs are completely hardcoded, so if you want to use this workflow with a new batch, you'll have to write the sample combinations you want there out by hand as well.